# Is it possible to stream large data (object) in spring

Tags: spring-boot, stream, in-memory

We construct a large object currently in java and send it as text/xml. It seems the client times out. Is it possible to convert this object in byte array or String and stream the data.
Will it help? We are using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE with Spring reactive, but it is expensive(too much CPU/Memory)

Ideally spring controlller should return

```
 return quasarService.findByReceivedStatus(organizationId, receiverId)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(delay))
                .cache()
                .take(50)
                .onBackpressureDrop()               
                .repeat(3) /// if repeat number not specified connection will keep long..
.parallel(50); //ParallelFlux
```